# Is it possible to upgrade physical disks in raid using hpacucli?

Tags: linux, raid

Is it possible to upgrade a RAID volume using hpacucli?  For instance, i have a 4 disk Raid-10 array.  If i replace each disk (of course allowing the raid to rebuild in each case), after all 4 disks have been upgraded, would hpacucli be able to extend the array size?

array A (SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)

```
  logicaldrive 1 (148.9 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 80.0 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA, 80.0 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SATA, 80.0 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SATA, 80.0 GB, OK)
```

I've looked at the hpacucli help docs, and i think the following command will do it.  What risks am i taking doing it live, or would single user mode be better?  Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.

=> ctrl slot=0 logicaldrive 1 modify size=max